# Papypal ExpressCheckout

Tags: paypal, php

Добрый день.
Вопрос касается платежки `paypal`.

Можно ли в `ExpressCheckout` задать параметр `notify_url` для IPN запросов с пайпала?

Если да, то какой именно параметр?

В `sandbox` запрашивается ли этот `nitify_url` пайпалом ?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот [тут](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted) в разделе Event Notification пишут, что Express Checkout поддерживает IPN. А сам адрес я задавал в аккаунте продавца (в sandbox тоже).
My Account -> Profile -> More Options -> Instant Payment Notification Preferences -> Choose IPN Settings -> указать Notification URL и разрешить Receive IPN messages (Enabled) -> Save

Comment: Ситуация.. Онлайн продажа товаров, собранная с разных продавцов.. Укаждого продавца свой пайавл аккаунт.. При выборе того или иного товара используется тот или иной пайпал аккаунт.. 

Остается задать notify_url. Вариант засетить в аккаунте хорошо.. если у вас всего два продавца.. а если их 20 ? 200 ?

Comment: А ну если так, то скорее всего придется отказаться от экспресса:[Dynamically Setting the Notification URL](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNSetup#id091GJ202030)

Comment: А вот еще, что говорят, вроде бы если поменять NOTIFYURL на PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL, то может сработать.

Comment: Ok, спасиб.. попробую.

Comment: И если не затруднит, результат сообщите, пожалуйста, для последующих поколений.

Comment: Сейчас вопрос немного не актуальный, но как вернусь к пайпалу, отпишусь ;)